# How could I prevent my .NET project from upgrading the minor version automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, testing, version

Yesterday my tests were working fine.

Today I start working and find out that my test fail. I investigate the issue and it turns out that now my project expects the `6.0.8` version of .NET, while yesterday it was happy with the `6.0.7`. So, I have to go and download the respective runtime for the tests to run. And here is what I have specified in my `.csproj`: `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`.

How could I avoid this involuntary version updates?

Comment: You can use the [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) config file

Comment: Did you update anything else in the meantime? Nuget packages etc? These things don't change randomly.

Comment: @DavidG, no, I changed nothing. Yesterday I was working on my local branch and today I open Visual Studio and see this issue. Nobody was doing any changes to my local branch. Seems like the `6.0.8` was released today and now Visual Studio is trying to use it all the time.